# How can Thread increment data insert into textveiw in Android studio with java

Tags: java, android

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int a =1;
        while (true) {
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tv_mainActivityBalance.setText(String.valueOf(a));
            System.out.println(a);
            a++;
        }
    }
};
thread.start();
```

I got result from my console `(from: System.out.println(a))`, but if got  error for set value in `Textveiw(tv_mainActivityBalance)`.

How can I set value in textView and how to it works automatically when thread change.

Comment: setText("" +a); here you go.

Comment: its not working bro.....error:Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: why you are using while loop.?

Comment: for infinite count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because to change  `tv_mainActivityBalance`  text you need the **UI thread**.
If you would post a bit more about your code and what it should do, then perhaps we could help you find a more optimal solution.

Nevertheless your code should look something like this.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int a =1;
        while (true){
            try {
                 sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final int tmp = a;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tv_mainActivityBalance.setText(String.valueOf(tmp));
                    }
                });
                System.out.println(a);
                a++;
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

their is no need to take tmp data, because of memory , we just use a variable to resolve this .

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int a =1;
            while (true){
                try {
                     sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    final int tmp = a;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tv_mainActivityBalance.setText(String.valueOf(tmp));
                        }
                    });
                    System.out.println(a);
                    a++;
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are coding, it's working for me. And give the value of a ,continuously by increasing 1.